# Get 5 highest values from a hashmap while preserving the insertion order

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, hashmap

I need to form a dictionary of most repeated strings from an ArrayList. If multiple strings have same frequency then the dictionary index(value) is based on the insertion order. First inserted gets the lowest index.

I have a LinkedHashMap  where I have counted the frequency of every word appearing in the ArrayList. Something Like this -

```
{
map.put("abcd1", 7);
map.put("abcd5", 8);
map.put("abcd4", 2);
map.put("abcd3", 10);
map.put("abcd2", 7);
map.put("abcd6", 5);
map.put("abcd7", 8);
}
```

What I need is another HashMap which is sorted both by value and if the values are same then by insertion order. Like this -

```
{
("abcd3", 0),
("abcd5", 1),
("abcd7", 2),
("abcd1", 3),
("abcd2", 4),
}
```

Searched online for long time but couldn't understand how do I do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is to sort the map by frequency and take the first 5 entries. You can do this e.g. using Java 8 streams:

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> getTop5ByValue(LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map) {
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Entry.<String, Integer> comparingByValue().reversed())
        .limit(5)
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                e -> e.getKey(),
                e -> index.getAndIncrement(),
                (k, v) -> {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate key " + k);
                },
                LinkedHashMap::new)
            );
}
```

Insertion order for words with equal frequency is handled by [`Stream#sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-), since that is a [*stable sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). The clumsy part is collecting the entries to a new ordered map with an index as value.

If you provide details on what specifically you didn't understand I can add further explanations.

Comment: Thanks @Marvin. I did not know about Streams until now.